Unable to do a callout from Managed Package Post-Install Script due to Permissions issue
I am distributing a Managed Package as part of a Salesforce Integration that I am building, and one of the requirements here is to send a callback request to my servers whenever users install/upgrade my package.
I am relying on Callouts and Post-Install scripts to send the HTTP callback but I am unable to do so.
I have a PostInstallHandler class set on my Managed Package that is responsible for sending the callout:
public class PostInstallHandler implements InstallHandler {
  public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
    if (context == null) {
      return;
    }

    // Perform the callout asynchronously
    ID installerId = context.installerId();
    ID organizationId = context.organizationId();
    String previousVersion = context.previousVersion()?.toString();
    Boolean isUpgrade = context.isUpgrade();

    sendCallback(
      installerId,
      organizationId,
      previousVersion,
      isUpgrade
    );
  }

  @future(callout=true)
  private static void sendCallback(
    ID installerId,
    ID organizationId,
    String previousVersion,
    Boolean isUpgrade
  ) {
    // Prepare the payload
    Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
    payload.put('installerId', installerId);
    payload.put('organizationId', organizationId);
    payload.put('previousVersion', previousVersion);
    payload.put('isUpgrade', isUpgrade);

    // Convert the payload to JSON
    String payloadJson = JSON.serialize(payload);

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(
      'callout:' + 'ExamplePackage__ExampleCredential' + '/callback'
    );
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setBody(payloadJson);

    // Send the request
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
  }
}

However, the callout in the Apex Job fails with the following error:
First error: We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "ExampleCredential" might not exist.

I have the Named Credential, and External Credential included in my Managed Package, and I have made sure that they exist and the callout code is correct by attempting to do the callout in the Developer Console, using the following code:
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(
  'callout:' +
    'ExamplePackage__ExampleCredential' +
    '/callback'
);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);

Executing that code in the Developer Console works just fine.
Upon doing some research, I have found out that the Post-Install context runs under a 'ghost' user with god permissons, so it is to my surprise that the callout fails with insufficient permissions.
I have tried different things to try and overcome this:
Trial 1: I tried creating a Permission Set with the External Credential Principle, assigning this permission set to the current user of the Post-Install job:
private static void assignPermissionSetToUser(ID userId) {
  String permissionSetApiName = 'IntegrationPermissions';

  // Query for the Permission Set
  PermissionSet permissionSet = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM PermissionSet
    WHERE Name = :permissionSetApiName
    LIMIT 1
  ];

  // Check if the installing user already has the Permission Set assigned
  Integer existingAssignments = [
    SELECT COUNT()
    FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE AssigneeId = :userId AND PermissionSetId = :permissionSet.Id
  ];

  // If no assignment exists, assign the Permission Set to the user
  if (existingAssignments == 0) {
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(
      AssigneeId = userId,
      PermissionSetId = permissionSet.Id
    );
    insert psa;
  }
}

@future(callout=true)
private static void sendCallback(
  ID installerId,
  ID organizationId,
  String previousVersion,
  Boolean isUpgrade
) {
  ID currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
  assignPermissionSetToUser(currentUserId);


  // callout code
}

However, when this executes, I get back the following error:
First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The user license doesn't allow External Credential Principal Access: []

Trial 2: I tried setting my Post-Install class as without sharing
Following the guidance of this answer, which states that setting the class as without sharing should grant all permissions to this class, but unfortunately, I received the same permissions error
First error: We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "ExampleCredential" might not exist. 


Can anyone provide guidance as to how I can do a Callout to my servers after a package installation?
